# Noetherian $1$-dimensional domain with ideal generated by more than $2$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

It is a classical theorem that in a Dedekind domain, every ideal can be generated by two or fewer elements. I was wondering what goes wrong if we omit the integrally closed property. I thought about, for example, $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ which is not integrally closed since it is missing the integral element $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. However, all of the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$ I can think of are still generated by at most two elements. For example,
$$(2,1+\sqrt{5})^2=(4,2+2\sqrt{5},6+2\sqrt{5})=(4,2+2\sqrt{5}).$$
Anyone know of an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A:=k[[t^3,t^5,t^7]], I:=(t^3,t^5,t^7), k$ a field. To show that $I$ is not generated by two elements, suppose $I=(f,g)$ where $f=f_3t^3+f_5t^5+f_6t^6+f_7t^7+\dots, g=g_3t^3+\dots$ . We have:$$\begin{cases}
t^3=pf+qg, \\
t^5=rf+sg, \\ 
t^7=uf+vg. 
\end{cases}
$$
By the first two equations, two vectors $(f_3,f_5),(g_3,g_5)$ are linearly independent. Then $u_0=v_0=0$ and $1=u_0f_7+v_0g_7$, contradiction.

Comment: Very nice! Was there any reason to take power series ring instead of the polynomial ring?

Comment: Not in particular :) My philosophy is that proving that a ring is one-dimensional is easier for power series ones.

Comment: And by modifying the example you can easily find examples in which the ideal needs many elements to be generated, btw

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Very interesting! Another thing about this example is that, unless I am mistaken, it seems every ideal is still generated by $3$ or fewer elements. Is it true that for a Noetherian one-dimensional domain, there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that every ideal is generated by $n$ or fewer elements?

Comment: If the ring R is one dimensional and Cohen Macaulay, then every ideal can be generated with e(R) elements, where e(R) is the multiplicity of R. In general, i think there is no bound but I'd have to go look...